# Creating Usable Path Variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a piece of software that works on multiple systems. The section of code I have become stuck on is as follows:

```
import shutil
from os import environ, getcwd

getUser = lambda: environ["USERNAME"] if "C:" in getcwd() else environ["USER"]
user = getUser()

source = r"C:\Users\ " + str(user) + r"\Downloads\Dub.exe"
source = source.replace(' ', '')
destination = r"C:\Users\ " + str(user) + r"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
destination = destination.replace(' ', '')


shutil.move(source, destination)
#destination = PurePath(destination)
# shutil.move(r"C:\Users\Jack\Downloads\Dub.exe", r"C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
# shutil.move(os.path.join("C:", "Users", str(user), "Downloads", 'Dub.exe'), os.path.join("C:", "Users", str(user), "AppData", "Roaming", "Microsoft", "Windows", "Start Menu", "Programs", "Startup"))
```

This simply moves a file from the download folder to the startup folder, the problem that arises is that the back slashed in variables 'source' and 'destination' get processed and become '//' which makes the path inept. The second to last line that has been commented out works but only works for my system as the user name is included in the raw string. If anyone has any suggestions or solutions please help :)

I have tried multiple methods from the 'Concatenate backslash on python' thread but none of them seemed to work and I continued to get the error of the double slash

Comment: [**`os.path.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is the usual way to join path parts

Comment: You have the path module which is designed to deal with different OS path and give you the needed one. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Well you get no such file because there is no such file. There is a space in "Start Menu". You can escape especial characters with backslah, so try replacing "Start Menu" with "Start\ Menu".

Comment: My startup directory is named "Start-up" on Windows 10.

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but I'm not quite clear on what you're seeing. Please try to separate it out: show each thing you tried *separately*, and the *exact* error you got with *that* thing you tries.

Comment: Sorry, the slashes cancelled each other out, os.path.join didn't work  (see commented out line) @PeterWood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup'

Right; the folder is `Start Menu`, not `StartMenu`. Removing spaces from the string was a mistake, presumably trying to fix this:

```
source = r"C:\Users\ " + str(user) + r"\Downloads\Dub.exe"
#                   ^
source = source.replace(' ', '')
```

The space after `C:\Users\` is not desired. It would be better not to have it in the first place, but as you've probably already seen, a raw string (made with `r""`) cannot end in a backslash.

We can avoid these problems by using string formatting:

```
source = rf"C:\Users\{user}\Downloads\Dub.exe"
```

However,

> the problem that arises is that the back slashed in variables 'source' and 'destination' get processed and become '//' which makes the path inept.

I don't quite understand what you mean by this. `/` in file paths *will work just fine* on Windows from a program; it's just not the most convenient thing at the command line. At any rate, `os.path.join` will use the appropriate file path separator for your system. And I have no idea where you would be getting `//` from.

It sounds like you might have tried it and seen `\\` in the results; this is fine and *represents a single backslash in the actual string* - Python escapes the string when displaying it back to you.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I think I got caught up using \ for paths. Thanks for the help